# SOLR - Count of results from Result Grouping

Tags: solr

I am using Result Grouping into the SOLR. How can i get the total number of results? By result I mean the count of grouped data.

For example:

[image]

I searched with 2 email addresses ("Kartikeshwar@sterlinghofman.com" OR "milojevics@mail.com"). I got 2 results in the result set. There is numFound attribute in the result node which shows the email address "milojevics@mail.com" matched 16 times and the email address "Kartikeshwar@sterlinghofman.com" matched 28 times. There is a matches attribute which shows the total number of matches (16 + 28 = 44). But i want to know the total number of result set which is 2 (1 for "Kartikeshwar@sterlinghofman.com" + 1 for "milojevics@mail.com"). How can i get that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the number of groups use the `groups.ngroups` request parameter which will give you the group count.

[Documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing#Request_Parameters) :-

```
group.ngroups
true/false
If true, includes the number of groups that have matched the query. Default is false.
```